# syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, cmd

I am new to writing scripts, in ubuntu.

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 skip=4" %%G IN ('svn info --revision HEAD') DO...
```

I get the following error -- "syntax error near unexpected token `('". Can someone tell me why I get this error?

Comment: That looks like Windows syntax!

Comment: Linux script haven't got the same command?

Comment: Yes, but not with the same syntax. Each time you see a ` \ ` for an option, it's for Windows.

Comment: In Linux, options are given with a dash, `for -x` where `x` is your option

Comment: @Classico yes, the syntax is quite different. BTW, even on Linux there are several shells of two main families: sh/bash/zsh/ash and csh/tcsh (these families' syntax really differs also). But for the beginning, stick with `bash`, its the standard shell for  Linux and OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically what you're trying to do is

1. Iterate through lines output by the command `svn info --revision HEAD`
2. Starting from line 5
3. Assigning the 2nd item/field/column to the variable `%%G`

One of the many ways to do it in Bash is

```
for variable in $(svn info --revision HEAD | awk 'NR>4 {print $2}'); do
  ... something fun ...
done
```

What this does is

1. You pipe/"send" the output of `svn info --revision HEAD` to `awk` command.
2. If the NR (number of records/lines processed so far) is greater than 4  (i.e. skips first 4 lines), `awk` prints out the 2nd column/field/item.
3. The whole `$(..)` is then replaced by the result of `awk` which is something like

   ```
   item2_line5
   item3_line6
   item2_line7
   ....
   ```
4. Due to Bash's word splitting, each line is treated as an item in a list, and `for` iterates through each item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your command is a **Windows** command: look at the Windows `FOR` documentation [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true).

If you're working in Ubuntu, type `man for` in the terminal and you will get the documentation.