# Bash returns "syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Tags: syntax, token

I am programming using IDL and unfortunately I decided to name a file using "(" and now I want to remove this file using "rm" but every time I try I get this same error message. It seems that I cannot copy or delete or doing anything with the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [syntax error near unexpected token \`('](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153101/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes

For eg. `rm -rf "abc(meow)pqr"`

Answer (score 1):

Use `?` in place of `(` when describing the file name.

```
rm -i ff?.txt
```

When asked `rm: remove regular file 'ff(.txt'?`, answer `y`.